# Div onclick function is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, onclick

the onlcick function is not working in the below case it always i have checked in ie8, and in some computer firefox and chrome also not working.

```
   $ad_div1='<div onclick="window.location=\''.$url.'\'">
   <a target="_blank" href="http://yahoo.com"> <img src="http://rose.com/abc.jpg"/></a>
    </div>';
```

but when i give an `alert` before `window.location` its working ie,

```
   $ad_div1='<div onclick="alert(1);window.location=\''.$url.'\'">
   <a target="_blank" href="http://yahoo.com"> <img src="http://rose.com/abc.jpg"/></a>
    </div>';
```

How to slove this problem?

Comment: are you getting any error in javascript console when you're trying with the first case?

Comment: @govindsinghnagarkoti HTML is case-insensitive.

Comment: may be due to double  qoutes inside single qoutes

Comment: Is that PHP you have? Because you can't concatenate strings using a `.` in javascript. If so, can you show the client-side generated script?

Comment: @RGraham i have written it inside php code

Comment: What you actually mean when you say "not working"? Nothing happens? Link opens a new page only? The window.location changes only? You can't see the content of `$ad_div1`? Something else?

Comment: @Teemu i need to open yahoo.com in a new window and in the same window i need to go the link which i have given in $url

Comment: Yes, but what happens instead?

Comment: i need to track the link for that i am using onclick function and in the other page i need to open the link here it is yahoo.com

Comment: @RoSe It's quite clear what you want, but you haven't described your problem. What happens that you don't want to happen? What your page does instead of what you want?

Comment: @Teemu it displays ads according to javascript code

Answer (score 1):

The code looks like it should produce code like this 
(when `$url = "http://example.com"` ):

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://example.com'">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://yahoo.com">
        <img src="http://rose.com/abc.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And this seems to work in Chrome and Firefox, [see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MmcXq/).
I'm guessing the $url variable is somehow wrong, look at the generated output of your code, does the onclick attribute look like my example the above?

**EDIT:**

Don't really understand why you want to do this, relying on javascript for tracking, and opening tabs/windows, etc...

Why not create a service on your server to do the tracking and redirect to the supplied url,
so you could simplify the link like this:

```
$ad_div1='<a target="_blank" 
    href="http:yourdomain.com/redirect?target=' . 
    urlencode($actualTargetUrl) . '">
    <img src="http://rose.com/abc.jpg" />
</a>';
```

Then using php (or some other server script) or rewrite rule the to handle all `/redirect*` urls on yourdomain.com that would 
log/register the request and give a 302 "moved temporarily" redirect to the url specified by the `target` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

And what exactly going on?

I suppose that when you click on link, browser fires event -> then event goes to yours div and eval code on yours "onclick" attribute -> then event goes to document and document change location based on your href attribute of your "a" element. And thats why your "onclick" not working.

You can try this solution:

```
onclick="var event = arguments[0] || window.event; event.stopPropagation();window.location='".$url."'"
```

Comment: Is there any solution for that?

Comment: The `a` has `target="_blank"` which supposed to open the `href` in a new window/tab. Rather `window.location` in the `div` changes the location before execution catches the `a`...?

Comment: You can try catch event and stop it propagation  - event.stopPropagation().

Comment: Oh, i understand.... You want open both locations? I am so stupid :(

Comment: @KillaBee yes, i want to open both locations

Comment: @KillaBee I guess so (I mean opening the locations ; )), but OP refuses to tell, what's the actual problem. Maybe eventhandling model in IE8 fires `onclick` for the `div` first, "`some computer firefox and chrome`" probably have pop-up blocker on or sth...